# Convert multidimensional array of folder paths to a nested folder structure array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an xml backup of my bricked music disk which I'm trying to access nicely to explore what folders (albums) and tracks were on there. So far I created an array containing all the file locations since that's how the xml was build. Every folder is separated by a comma. Now I want it all merged and converted to an array that has a folder structure. From there on I can use that array to build an explorer-like interface to browse trough my old music tracks.

The below array is an example of what I have now and want to convert:

```
[
    [x, xy, xya, {file: one}],
    [x, xy, xya, {file: two}],

    [x, xy, xyz, {file: one}],

    [x, xy, {file: one}],

    [x, xz, {file: one}],
    [x, xz, {file: two}],

    [x, {file: one}],
    [x, {file: two}],

    [y, {file: one}]
]
```

I want the above array converted into something like below:

```
[
    {folder: x,
     content:
     [
         {folder: xy,
          content:
          [
              {folder: xya,
               content:
               [
                   {file: one},
                   {file: two}
               ]
              },
              {folder: xyz,
               content:
               [
                   {file: one}
               ]
              },
              {file: one}
          ]
         },
         {folder: xz,
          content:
          [
              {file: one},
              {file: two}
          ]
         },
         {file: one},
         {file: two}
     ]
    },
    {folder: y,
     content:
     [
         {file: one}
     ]
    }
]
```

I keep experimenting but still haven't found an accurate solution. Any ideas?

Comment: in the first code you have multi dimensional array, in the code above you have objects inside array.

Comment: You can try with a recursive functions. Check the element type is_array, is_object array_key_exists to identify if is a folder or a file, etc

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll keep trying things. Probably adding `type: folder` to folders and `type: file` to files would be easier to handle instead of using recursive functions for that matter. But still haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve my goal. I did it with the below code, which is the complete code. I even managed to skip the first array form and generate the second form instantly (see my question for the arrays I mean). My solution:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var data = [], dataLength, datanest, datanestLength;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var doc = this.responseXML,
                tr = doc.getElementsByTagName('tr'), trLength = tr.length;

            var filedir, level, levelLength;
            for (var i = 1; i < trLength; i++) {
                filedir = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[7].innerHTML;
                // filedir is formed like "foldername\foldername\filename.ext" etc.
                level = filedir.split('\\');
                levelLength = level.length;
                for (var j = 0; j < levelLength; j++) {

                    if (j == 0 && j < levelLength - 1) {
                        dataLength = data.length;
                        if (dataLength == 0 ||
                            data[dataLength - 1].type == 'file' ||
                            data[dataLength - 1].Name !== level[j]) {
                            data.push({
                                type: 'folder',
                                Name: level[j],
                                content: []
                            });
                        }
                        datanest = data[data.length - 1].content;

                    } else if (j < levelLength - 1) {
                        datanestLength = datanest.length;
                        if (datanestLength == 0 ||
                            datanest[datanestLength - 1].type == 'file' ||
                            datanest[datanestLength - 1].Name !== level[j]) {
                            datanest.push({
                                type: 'folder',
                                Name: level[j],
                                content: []
                            });
                        }
                        datanest = datanest[datanest.length - 1].content;

                    } else {
                        if (j == 0) { datanest == data; }
                        datanest.push({
                            type: 'file',
                            Track: tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[3].innerHTML,
                            Title: tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML,
                            Artist: tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML,
                            Time: tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[2].innerHTML,
                            Release: tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[4].innerHTML,
                            'Release Date': tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[8].innerHTML,
                            Label: tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[5].innerHTML,
                            Genre: tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[6].innerHTML,
                            File: level[j]
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(data);//SUCCESS
        }
    };
    xhttp.open('GET', 'backup.xml', true);
    xhttp.send();
};
```

I know it's not an exact answer to my question. It solved my problem I had, but in a little different way than I thought it had to be solved (converting the array).